# Windows Phone 8 Silverlight JSON Deserealize

Tags: c#, json, silverlight, serialization

I want to parse some json data in my Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight project. I created classes and deserialize object. Everytime it returns null value. Where did I do wrong? Thanks in advance...

JSON

```
{ "full": 1, "version": "*1.7.569*", "model": "MiCasaVerde VeraLite",             "zwave_heal": 1, "temperature": "C", "skin": "mios", "serial_number":     "35101436", "fwd1": "vera-us-oem-relay31.mios.com", "fwd2": "vera-us-oem-    relay12.mios.com", "mode": 2, "sections": [ { "name": "My Home", "id": 1 } ],     "rooms": [ ], "scenes": [ ], "devices": [ { "name": "Duman Sensoru", "altid":     "11", "id": 24, "category": 4, "subcategory": 4, "room": 0, "parent": 1, "armed": "1", "tripped": "0", "armedtripped": "0", "lasttrip": "1430755895", "batterylevel": "100", "temperature": "26" }, { "name": "Hareket Sensoru", "altid": "9", "id": 19, "category": 4, "subcategory": 3, "room": 0, "parent": 1, "armed": "1", "tripped": "0", "lasttrip": "1430779873", "armedtripped": "0", "batterylevel": "94", "temperature": "24", "light": "0", "humidity": "51" }, { "name": "Isik Sensoru", "altid": "m3", "id": 21, "category": 18, "subcategory": 0, "room": 0, "parent": 19, "light": "0" }, { "name": "Kapı Kilidi", "altid": "10", "id": 23, "category": 7, "subcategory": 0, "room": 0, "parent": 1, "pincodes": "<VERSION=3>1\t1,0;\t2,0;\t3,0;\t4,0;\t5,0;\t6,0;\t7,0;\t8,0;\t9,0;\t10,0;\t11,0;\t12,0;\t13,0;\t14,0;\t15,0;\t16,0;\t17,0;\t18,0;\t19,0;\t20,0;\t", "locked": "1", "batterylevel": "96", "state": -1, "comment": "" }, { "name": "Nem Sensoru", "altid": "m5", "id": 22, "category": 16, "subcategory": 0, "room": 0, "parent": 19, "humidity": "51" }, { "name": "On\/Off Switch", "altid": "8", "id": 18, "category": 3, "subcategory": 0, "room": 0, "parent": 1, "status": "1", "state": -1, "comment": "" }, { "name": "Pencere&Kapi Sensoru", "altid": "7", "id": 10, "category": 4, "subcategory": 1, "room": 0, "parent": 1, "armed": "1", "tripped": "0", "lasttrip": "1419667909", "armedtripped": "0", "batterylevel": "88" }, { "name": "Priz", "altid": "2", "id": 3, "category": 3, "subcategory": 0, "room": 0, "parent": 1, "status": "0", "watts": "0", "kwh": "0.0000", "state": -1, "comment": "" }, { "name": "Temperature Sensor", "altid": "m1", "id": 20, "category": 17, "subcategory": 0, "room": 0, "parent": 19, "temperature": "24" }, { "name": "Termometre", "altid": "m1", "id": 25, "category": 17, "subcategory": 0, "room": 0, "parent": 24, "temperature": "26" } ], "categories": [ { "name": "On\/Off Switch", "id": 3 }, { "name": "Sensor", "id": 4 }, { "name": "Doorlock", "id": 7 }, { "name": "Humidity Sensor", "id": 16 }, { "name": "Temperature Sensor", "id": 17 }, { "name": "Light Sensor", "id": 18 } ], "ir": 0, "irtx": "", "loadtime": 1431434160, "dataversion":     434160216, "state": -1, "comment": "" }
```

Class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace deneme
{
    class Zwave
    {
        public Section section { get; set; }
        public Device device { get; set; }
        public Category category { get; set; }
        public RootObject rootobject { get; set; }

        public class Section
        {
            public string name { get; set; }
            public int id { get; set; }
        }

        public class Device
        {
            public string name { get; set; }
            public string altid { get; set; }
            public int id { get; set; }
            public int category { get; set; }
            public int subcategory { get; set; }
            public int room { get; set; }
            public int parent { get; set; }
            public string armed { get; set; }
            public string tripped { get; set; }
            public string armedtripped { get; set; }
            public string lasttrip { get; set; }
            public string batterylevel { get; set; }
            public string temperature { get; set; }
            public string light { get; set; }
            public string humidity { get; set; }
            public string pincodes { get; set; }
            public string locked { get; set; }
            public int? state { get; set; }
            public string comment { get; set; }
            public string status { get; set; }
            public string watts { get; set; }
            public string kwh { get; set; }
        }

        public class Category
        {
            public string name { get; set; }
            public int id { get; set; }
        }

        public class RootObject
        {
            public int full { get; set; }
            public string version { get; set; }
            public string model { get; set; }
            public int zwave_heal { get; set; }
            public string temperature { get; set; }
            public string skin { get; set; }
            public string serial_number { get; set; }
            public string fwd1 { get; set; }
            public string fwd2 { get; set; }
            public int mode { get; set; }
            public List<Section> sections { get; set; }
            public List<object> rooms { get; set; }
            public List<object> scenes { get; set; }
            public List<Device> devices { get; set; }
            public List<Category> categories { get; set; }
            public int ir { get; set; }
            public string irtx { get; set; }
            public int loadtime { get; set; }
            public int dataversion { get; set; }
            public int state { get; set; }
            public string comment { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

Function

```
HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
                var json = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(new Uri("http://xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx/data_request?id=lu_sdata"));
                Zwave returned=JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Zwave>(json);
                var listed = returned.device.name;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you posted your JSON to http://json2csharp.com/ and used the classes in provided -- good so far.  But then you nested them in some outer class `Zwave` and tried to deserialize that, which is not correct.  You need to do:

```
var returned = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Zwave.RootObject>(json);
```

Or better yet, remove them from the `Zwave` container class and do

```
var returned = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
```

Next, your JSON contains an array of `"device"` objects -- 10 in fact -- which get deserialized as a `List<Device>`.  So if you want all their names, you need to do:

```
var listed = returned.devices.Select(d => d.name).ToList();
```

which gives:

> ```
> ["Duman Sensoru","Hareket Sensoru","Isik Sensoru","Kapı Kilidi","Nem Sensoru","On/Off Switch","Pencere&Kapi Sensoru","Priz","Temperature Sensor","Termometre"]
> ```